# UINavigationBar Backbutton quits app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a Navigation Controller in my app delegate that i am using to switch between views and that seems to work fine clicking the back button in the NavigationBar, but only when i have a UITable in the mix. But when i pushRootviewController to a standard root view controller i still see the back button in the UINavigationBar but when i click it the program quits and logs no errors.

I thought maybe something like this would work, but no luck.

```
CoCoachAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIBarButtonItem *iButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(playThis:)];
appDelegate.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = iButton;
[iButton release];
```

Anyone have something similar happen? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: How is `playThis:` implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you set the button to the navigation controller itself. you should be setting the button to the navigationItems of your Controllers inside your Navigation Controller (and remember that the backBarButtonItem is displayed on the navigation bar when the next (follow-up) view controller is visible. if that is not the behaviour you want, you should use leftBarButtonItem.) also remember that "back buttons" should have target/action set to nil as the navigation controller adds itself als target when you use it as backBarButtonItem.

Comment: why is it that if i dont put any sort of UIBarButton there when i switch views I still get a back button, but it just doesnt work?

Comment: how do you "switch views"? if you use pushViewController:animated: you should be fine

Comment: but even if i remove that code that i posted above, the app still shows a back button, but quits when i click it